When querying from GSheets table through BigQuery, successful using UI but failed using client given all permissions granted
I encountered the error below when trying to query GSheets table through BigQuery API via Cloud Composer job and DBeaver client.
Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

GDrive permission and BQ table permission has been granted to both personal account and service account, querying aforementioned table from BigQuery console is successful and returned expected results. Checking Job History -> Project History of same queries used by same principal shows console query is successful while client query has failed. Would like to ask for help to identify where are the lacking permissions.
